# .htaccess 301 redirect adds a trailing slash .xml/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following redirect in my `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/feed/podcast https://feeds.blubrry.com/feeds/show-name.xml
```

Unfortunately, if I visit `https://example.com/blog/feed/podcast/` this redirects to `https://feeds.blubrry.com/feeds/show-name.xml/` and that doesn't load due to the `.xml/` part.

I have already tried adding `Redirect 301 /blog/feed/podcast/ https://feeds.blubrry.com/feeds/show-name.xml` as well, but it doesn't change anything.

Here is what I see using curl:

```
$ curl -IL https://example.com/blog/feed/podcast/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 30 Oct 2022 16:11:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://feeds.blubrry.com/feeds/show-name.xml/

HTTP/2 403 
x-amz-error-code: AccessDenied
x-amz-error-message: Access Denied
date: Sun, 30 Oct 2022 16:11:23 GMT
server: AmazonS3
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 bdb480ba487636e194d63f984ed846f2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: TXL50-P1
x-amz-cf-id: 6ggR-YtQJ2nA8qCkZvQXioMdEazP22NXVSvulPm7GvDF45tMohtmeQ==
```

Comment: Sry you're right, I messed up the description. When I visit `https://example.com/blog/feed/podcast` it's fine, the issue is when I visit `https://example.com/blog/feed/podcast/` -> which Google unfortunately crawls and the search console shows me an error `Blocked due to access forbidden (403)`. I have edited the question and the curl output accordingly

Comment: The config/code responsible for that redirect is not on the question. The title of the question also does not match the behavior you go on to describe. Please edit the question to address

Comment: What do you mean by code? `Redirect 301 /blog/feed/podcast https://feeds.blubrry.com/feeds/show-name.xml` is the "code" in my `.htaccess`.

Comment: That does not seem likely to be the entire contents of your .htaccess file, and if it _Is_ the redirect does not originate from your .htaccess file and you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `which Google unfortunately crawls` btw Google only follows urls I can see - that means this wrong-url is/was in the page source. That’s something else find and fix. The title of the question is still wrong :)